# Firebase.initializeApp doesn't work on Flutter web

Tags: flutter, firebase

My Flutter web app doesn't start if I initialize Firebase. It gives me this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment.

I tried with older Firebase versions. It works perfectly with android and iOS.

Errors:

localhost/:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
at [dartx.append] (html_dart2js.dart:23474:33)
at firebase_core_web.FirebaseCoreWeb.new.injectSrcScript (firebase_core_web.dart:138:14)
at injectSrcScript.next ()
at runBody (async_patch.dart:84:54)
at Object._async [as async] (async_patch.dart:123:5)
at firebase_core_web.FirebaseCoreWeb.new.injectSrcScript (firebase_core_web.dart:106:31)
at MappedIterator.new. (firebase_core_web.dart:171:16)
at MappedIterator.new.moveNext (iterable.dart:393:20)
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqZSr.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hjAq.png)

Comment: errors.dart:288 Uncaught (in promise) Error: NoSuchMethodError: 'ff_trigger_firebase_app-check'
method not found
Receiver: Instance of 'Window'
Arguments: [Instance of 'LegacyJavaScriptObject']

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Comment: Can you share your index.html file and pubspec.yaml?